# How to make Push notification server for my android application?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, webserver

How i can make my own push notification server for my android & ios application?
m not wanna to use GCM.

Comment: Check out this link it will guide you with full explanation on how to create android application and register it for push notification on GCM server and how to 3rd party App Server to handle and throw push notification 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCM and APN are the client side part of the infrastructure. You should still set up your own messaging server. That event-based server will then push messages to the clients via the proprietary infrastructure. I think applications should be respectful of their enironment, and using the push facilities of the platform is indeed a good thing for your users. Also, it should be even easier for you to implement, thanks to the standard setup and the working documentation.

Otherwise, just pick your favourite message queue middleware (Active, Zero, you name it) and integrate it directly with the native client for the supported platforms, without using GCM (or Apple push). But be warned that this will make your application less efficient, and you may face higher development costs to set up the background notification service.

Answer (score 1):

Node.JS provide a module called SOCKET.IO.  I use this in my android apps for live messaging. You can configure it on AWS, Digitalocean Or you can use Heroku.

Here is the good example of Socket.io with android  http://nkzawa.tumblr.com/post/46850605422/connecting-to-a-socketio-server-from-android

Android chat app wit socketio

https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat